# Why this query never ends?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following situations

This never ends

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4 
      From Table A 
      ORDER BY A.Column1, A.Column2) 
WHERE ROWNUM < 16
```

These two queries run faster:

Query #1

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4 
From Table A 
ORDER BY A.Column1, A.Column2
```

Query #2

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4 
      From Table A) 
WHERE ROWNUM < 16
```

As you noticed, on the last one I removed the `ORDER BY`.

The query that never ends it happends on DataBaseA, but when I try to execute it on DatabaseB it just runs fast. So my question is why is it happening? Is it about an index issue? I checked that and TableA has 2 indexes more on DatabaseA than DatabaseB, but the extra indexes are on columns that are not on the query.

I hope you can help me

Comment: how many records are in the underlying table?

Comment: There are a lot, I didn't mentioned that because I thought it was not important, as the second case and third case work fine and fast. I didn't mentioned this as well but there are filters also, and with that filters the query throws no row

Comment: What are the query plans on the two different databases?

Comment: If the second query runs fast, the first should as well.

Comment: Query #2 is a red herring, it just says fetch me any old 16 rows from Table. To output from Query #0 or #1 the rows must be sorted first. The advantage Query #1 has it that is contains no subqueries, therefore can use indexes with a "SORT NO-SORT" strategy. NO-SORT says just follow the indexes without having  to fire up the memory/disk based sorting engine which on a "big" number of rows will take ages. As @JustinCave says the answer is in the explain plan difference. I'm only guessing based on what I've seen Oracle do before.